# How to check what permissions another app has been granted

Tags: java, android, permissions

Can I use  `checkPermission (String permName, String pkgName)` or something similar inside my application to check other apps granted permissions?

for example If I want to check if app1 which is installed in my device granted `android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS` , can I use `checkPermission` to check that in my app or not ?
I know the new release of marshmallow allow users to revoke some permissions, for that I want to check it

If that is not allowed please suggest alternative method.
[This more information about checkPermission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#checkPermission(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: Unclear and / or too broad. And "Why isn't my code working?".

Comment: It's that kind of humor you will appreciate when you will have some more reputation... ;)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I hope it's clear now

Answer (score 6):

`PERMISSION_GRANTED` is a number. Specifically, [it has a value of 0](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#PERMISSION_GRANTED). You cannot use a number to check anything.

You *can* [use `checkPermission()` on `PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#checkPermission%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to see whether a particular app (identified by its application ID, a.k.a. package name) holds a particular permission. That method returns either `PERMISSION_GRANTED` or `PERMISSION_DENIED`.

However, note that on Android 6.0+ devices, if the app you are checking is compiled with a `targetSdkVersion` of 22 or lower, `checkPermission()` will return `PERMISSION_GRANTED` so long as the permission was requested in the manifest (at least for `normal` and `dangerous` permissions, which are usually the ones that concern you). While the user can "revoke permissions" from those apps via the Settings app, that status is not reported by `checkPermission()`, and indeed I know of no way to find out whether the user revoked permissions from an app this way. You may see similar behavior on some custom ROMs that added this sort of permission control mechanism prior to Android 6.0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know it's return number, but the thing I'm looking for is there a way that I can use to check if the permissions revoked by user or not?  and you said no . thank you